# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on eval

Tags: javascript

I looked up the problem in other questions but didn't find an awnser.
chrome gives the error on this line:

```
var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

"data" is an array of Strings.

any suggestions?

Comment: Well... the error is in `data`... And the bad idea was to use `eval`.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use `eval` to parse JSON. Don't do that. Use `JSON.parse(data)` instead.

Comment: You know there's a `JSON.parse` function ? Most often it's the right solution to parse JSON (if you can't spot the error in your JSON, it's definitively the right one).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help but the "eval" is not the problem.

I used:

```
console.log(data);
```

and found out the problem is in "data".